# Finding a string and adding a number to it in Haskell

Tags: string, haskell

Suppose I have a multi-line string `multiStr`:

```
line 1
line 2
x.tally: 10
line 4
line 5
```

How could I write a function

```
f :: Integer -> String -> String -> String
f n lineMatcher multiStr = ...
```

that finds the first matching line that starts with `lineMatcher` and adds `n` to the number at the end of it.

So for example, in this case, we would have that `f 5 "x.tally" multiStr` evaluates to

```
line 1
line 2
x.tally: 15
line 4
line 5
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions generally have to include an attempt or more specificity as to where the road-block lays.

Comment: @Thomas and @Chad: I crafted the type signature of the function and named the arguments, and then outlined the needed specs with an example. I could qualitatively also say that I thought about `split`ing the multi-line string into different lines and then matching on those lines, but then didn't know what to do afterwards (eventually, I think we'll also have to `read` the number as an Integer). I appreciate your help.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson While this does make the question less good than it might have been, and is an issue worth raising in the comments, I don't think it makes it off-topic (unless you consider it too broad for asking for too much code without an attempt).

Comment: It is too broad. Writing a type signature and documenting the expected output is not an attempt at actually writing the code. That's just specifying the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to spoil the fun of solving this problem therefore I will only give some advice on how I would go and try solving this problem.

First of all I hope you know about the two functions `words` and `unwords` one is for splitting a `String` into a `[String]`, and the other does the opposite - i.e. joins a `[String]` separating two elements by a single `' '`. You should also know about the functions `lines` and `unlines` which do something quite similar - I hope you can guess by their name what they do.

Next thing I would try is building a (helper) transformation function that transforms a `String` by adding `n`. Hint: the function `show` might come in handy.

```
h :: Int -> String -> String
h n str = let m = read str
          in ...
```

If you can furthermore transform `["x.tally:", "10"]` into `["x.tally:", "15"]` with the previous helper function and map every other list to itself, then you are almost done and I hope you can stitch all of my advice together to make the function you desire.